# Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'some View' - why not?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, swift-protocols, opaque-types

I am trying to create a structure that's holding the dynamic configuration of a popup view. That includes an array of `actionButtons` as well as a `body` property that will make up the later popup. The body can be seen as the "child views" of the popup, such as text for example. I want to be able to specify child views at will, using the `@ViewBuilder` in my initializer.

However, I am getting the following error:

`Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'some View' (type of 'PopupConfiguration.body')`

```swift
public struct PopupConfiguration {
    let headline: String
    private(set) var body: some View = EmptyView()
    let actionButtons: [ActionButtonDefinition]

    init(headline: String, @ViewBuilder bodyContent: () -> some View, actionButtons: [ActionButtonDefinition]) {
        self.headline = headline
        self.body = bodyContent() // Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'some View' (type of 'PopupConfiguration.body')
        self.actionButtons = actionButtons
    }
}
```

I am confused now, since the compiler should be able to assign `some View` to `some View`, right? It's literally the same type, or not?

Can anyone please explain why this generates above shown error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of generics in this case:

```swift
public struct PopupConfiguration<Content: View> {
    let headline: String
    private(set) var body: Content
    let actionButtons: [ActionButtonDefinition]

    init(headline: String, @ViewBuilder bodyContent: () -> Content, actionButtons: [ActionButtonDefinition]) {
        self.headline = headline
        self.body = bodyContent()
        self.actionButtons = actionButtons
    }
}
```

I recommend you read the [opaque types documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html), especially the section "Differences Between Opaque Types and Protocol Types" :)

The main takeaway is that an opaque type refers to one specific type and retains said type informations. In your case, there is no guarantee that `var body: some View` and `content: () -> some View` will have the same type.

Comment: ahh makes sense... I didn't look at it that way